# Ловля исключений, почему студия говорит, что типы исключений идиентичны

Tags: java, android-studio

В блоке try есть код который может вызвать исключения типа    `MalformedURLException`, `ProtocolException` и `IOException`. Первый и второй типы являются подтипами (вернее наверно классы говорить) IOException.

Если я поставлю блок с IOException, то нижние блоки ничего уже не получат, об этом скажет студия. Если я ставлю так как в приложенном коде, то на нижние блоки студия ругается так: ***catch branch identical to 'MalformedURLException'*** . Т.е. пишет что каждый нижний блок идиентичен тому что сверху.  Почему? они ведь  оба входят в IOException и ловят разные исключения.

```
     try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setReque

stMethod("GET");
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                int code = connection.getResponseCode();

                if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf8"));
                    answer = "";
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        answer += line;
                    }
                    reader.close();
                }
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (MalformedURLException urlException) {
                urlException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException protocolException) {
                protocolException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае студия предлагает вам оптимизировать код, сократив его, т.к. хоть все исключения и не наследуют друг друга, обрабатываете вы их идентично. Т.е. вам можно так записать их обработку, в одном блоке `catch`:

```
  try {
        //код выбрасываюсь все перечисленные в catch исключения
      } catch (MalformedURLException | ProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
        catch (IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace(); //здесь студия снова будет говорить,что код идиентичен 
       }                          //тому, что выше,так как это общий предок 
                                 //для верхних исключений. Но если я его 
                                 //обработаю по-другому, например приведу к 
                                 //  строке и выведу в лог, то студия перестанет ругаться.
```

Comment: ммм, понятно. Мне в начале показалось палочка как оператор или используется, но нет, это просто разделитель. Ответ я ваш поправил , так как IOException исключение родитель двух других.